# How to create and publish a web service websphere?

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I wonder how a web service is published in websphere?, recently perform the following tutorial:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

My question is, how do I do the same with websphere? I do not wish to create axis, otherwise as hece in this example, without help from the IDE.

regards

Comment: This is very,very old tutorial. In WebSphere it is much simpler as all the required jars are provided by server. Just create dynamic web project, using 3.0 API, create Java class using `@WebService` annotation and Add to server (if from Eclipse). You're done. Your service should be available at `http://localhost:9080/webProjectName/ServiceName?wsdl

Comment: but the wsdl published does with axis2 and what I want is to respect the way I do it using jax-ws only

Comment: The way I wrote, creates axis2 jax-ws service, exactly what you want. I don't understand what you mean in the comment. Tutorial is for Tomcat, which is not Java EE server, thats why you need custom bootstrap in web.xml. WebSphere has integrated web service engine, thats why it is much easier to publish there.

Comment: thanks, the question is that when a web service with jax-ws create the wsdl created is different as is done axis and axis2 integrates're right websphere